# KIVY python virtual keyboard

Tags: python, kivy, virtual-keyboard

how to make python KIVY onscreen keyboard numeric only? im using `Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')` and its working but there is the whole keyboard, I just need numerics

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need to create a keyboard JSON file like [these](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/kivy/data/keyboards), add it to the correct path (the default layout_path is `<kivy_data_dir>/keyboards/`), and set it onto the keyboard_layout value.

```
Config.setdefault('widgets', 'keyboard_layout', 'numeric')
```

Where your JSON template file is `numeric.json`.